# Determinant of sparse matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, determinants

I'm implementing a sparse matrix class , using a vector of map for store the data (the map represents a row of matrix in which the key is the index of columns and the value is the value of the maitrix in this position ) 
I have wrote the function for calculating the determinant but I don't know if there is a way for compute this saving time (since the matrix is sparse and most of the value is zero ) 
here my implementation :

```
template <typename T>
T det(const SparseMatrix<T>& a )
{
      T d =0 ; // value of determinant ! 
      std::size_t row  = a.getRows() ;
      std::size_t cols = a.getCols() ;

      if(row == cols) // square Matrix;
      {     

         if(row == 1)   
         {
            d = a(1,1);  // matrix 1x1
         }
         else if(row == 2) 
         {
            d = a(1,1) * a(2,2) - a(2,1) * a (1,2);
         }
         else // 3x3 of greather ..
         {  
              for(std::size_t c = 1 ; c <= cols ; c++ )
              {
                  SparseMatrix<T> m = a.minors(1,c);
                  d += pow(-1,1+c) * a(1,c) * det(m) ;
              }
         }
      }
      else
      {
          throw std::runtime_error("Matrix must be square! Error occured in SparseMatrix::det()");   
      }
      return d ;
}
```

and this is the class interface

```
template <typename element_type>
class SparseMatrix {

  public:
   template<class T>
   friend SparseMatrix<T> operator+(const SparseMatrix<T>& m1 , const SparseMatrix<T>& m2 );  

   template<class T>
   friend SparseMatrix<T> operator-(const SparseMatrix<T>& m1 , const SparseMatrix<T>& m2 );  

   template <class T>
   friend SparseMatrix<T> operator*(const SparseMatrix<T>& m1 , const SparseMatrix<T>& m2  );

   template <class T>
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out , const SparseMatrix<T>& m);

   template <class T>
   friend SparseMatrix<T> dot(const SparseMatrix<T>& m1 , const SparseMatrix<T>& m2  );

   template <class T>
   T det(const SparseMatrix<T>& a );




  public:
    // container type ;  
    using data_type = std::vector<std::map<std::size_t , element_type >> ;
    using it_rows   = typename std::map<std::size_t , element_type>::iterator ; 

    constexpr SparseMatrix(std::size_t rows , std::size_t cols) : rows{rows} , columns{cols}
    {
       data.resize(rows);     
    }

    SparseMatrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<element_type>> l );

    SparseMatrix(const std::string );  


    auto insert(std::size_t i , std::pair<std::size_t, element_type> p )
    { 
       assert( i < rows && p.first < columns); // , "Index out of bound" );
       data.at(i).insert(p);
    }

    auto insert(std::size_t i, std::size_t j, element_type val)
    {
      assert(i<rows && j <columns);
      data.at(i)[j] = val ;
    }

    auto identity() noexcept ;

    auto diag(const element_type& v) noexcept ;

    auto print() const noexcept ; 

    auto dataType() const noexcept ;

    auto traspose() noexcept ;

    auto printf()const noexcept ;

    constexpr auto getRows() const noexcept { return rows; }  

    constexpr auto getCols() const noexcept { return columns; } 

    SparseMatrix<element_type> operator*=(const SparseMatrix<element_type>) ;

    const element_type operator()(std::size_t , std::size_t) const noexcept ;  

    element_type operator()(std::size_t , std::size_t) noexcept ;  

    constexpr SparseMatrix<element_type> minors(const std::size_t , const std::size_t ) const;  

  private:

    std::size_t rows    ;
    std::size_t columns ;
      data_type data    ;     // vector containing row element 


};
```

what's looks like the way in which i calculate the determinant ? 
consider that the operator() is overloaded in this way

```
template <typename T>
T SparseMatrix<T>::operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) noexcept 
{
      i -= 1 ;
      j -= 1 ;
      if(data.at(i).find(j) != data.at(i).end()) 
      {
         return data.at(i).at(j) ;
      }
      else
      {
         return 0.0 ;    
      }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I am slightly surprised you are not using `std::map<std::pair<size_t, size_t>, double>`, then you want operator() to be `const auto it = data.find(std::make_pair(i, j); return it == data.end() ? 0.0 : *it;`.

Comment: That should be a lot more compact (and avoids a double look-up in the map, and the pointless -1.)  Ooo!  Also, you don't want `map`, you want `unordered_map`.

Comment: @MartinBonner I found vector of map more adapt .. you don't ? give me an example of the advantage ! thanks for your help

Comment: @martin you actually want to know where gaps are, so ordered may be better.  Or you need gap data to be stored somehow.

Comment: IMHO you will not lose your time reading more about numerical linear algebra. We generally never store sparse matrices using a coordinate approach but we prefer dedicated storages like the CRS one. We generally never compute determinant of big matrices. You have very good free online book about sparse matrices, like these ones: http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/books.html

Comment: @PicaudVincent what is the CRS ? could you give me an example ?

Comment: @MarcoGhiani (sorry I was out).. CRS is for compressed row storage, decribed in wiki for instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix

Comment: @MarcoGhiani, please do not see any offense in my remarks, it is just that IMHO there are some books that you really need to read before implementing a sparse matrix lib. Also concerning determinant, we try to avoid  such computations and we avoid minor rules (because of algorithm complexity and numerical pb). If you really need determinant, prefer QR factorization approach or a dedicated algorithm like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%E2%80%93LeVerrier_algorithm if the problem is not too ill-conditioned

Comment: I didn't see any offense !! I would learning ! so I say you Thanks a lot for let me notice that there is a better way for doing so !!! your contribute was illuminating !!

Comment: I can just ask you if have some example for illustrating the explanation

Comment: I really don't understand IA and JA .. in the second example of the wiki IA has less cordinate than JA .. how it's works ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to construxt minors without allocatijg a new copy of everything; you need minor views.

A minor view has a pointer to its source matrix and some efficient way of describing which columns and rows are skipped.

You want to be able to skip empty columns/rows easy, and fast-iterate without checking each entry.  So you may want to store a map of map to start, then improve to rle compressed vectors and/or skip lists.  If ypur matrix is truly sparse, checking for zero at each index can dominate your calculations.